# Handling Reference Types

Tags: c#, reference, types

When reference variable can be passed by reference :

```
    class Example
    {
        public string str="Demo";

        public int[] intValues={1,3,4,5};

       public static void StrPassing(string someStr)
        {
            string otherStr="Changed!";
            someStr=otherStr;
        }

        public static void NumPassing(int[] a)
        {
            a[2] = 115;
        }

    }


       static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Example ex = new Example();
            Example.StrPassing(ex.str);
            Example.NumPassing(ex.intValues);

            foreach (int i in ex.intValues)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(ex.str);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

the value of `intValues[2]` is changed as `115` as the reference is being passed.But the value of the string "str" (demo) is not changed to "Changed!".What is the reason for it?.can i take it as Arrays are passed by reference and other reference types are passed by
value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to distinguish between changing *which object a variable refers to* and changing *the content of the object".

In this code:

```
public static void StrPassing(string someStr)
{
    string otherStr="Changed!";
    someStr=otherStr;
}
```

... you are changing the value of `someStr`. You're not making any change to the string that `someStr` originally refers to. Indeed, you can't because strings are immutable. (If it were a `StringBuilder`, you could set the length to 0 and then append "Changed!")

Changing the value of `someStr` has no effect because the argument (`ex.str`) was passed by value. (The value in question *is* a reference, but that doesn't mean it's passed *by* reference.)

Now compare that with this code:

```
public static void NumPassing(int[] a)
{
    a[2] = 115;
}
```

Here you're *not* changing the value of `a` - you're changing the contents of the array that `a` refers to.

In short, unless you use `ref`/`out`, arguments will be passed by value - but for reference types that value is just a reference.

I have an [article on parameter passing](http://pobox.com/~skeet/csharp/parameters.html) which goes into all of this in a lot more detail.

Answer (score 5):

Whatever you pass to a method as arguments is passed by value which, for reference types, means that *a reference* is passed by value. So you can't change the *object* to another one but you can surely change its *contents* (because that doesn't change the actual reference, just some memory elsewhere).

As your example with the array demonstrates you take the array reference (but don't change it) and change a value *in* the array. This is just like taking some object and changing a property value. You can do this just fine from within a method too.

If you want to change a string, which is an immutable object in .NET, then you need to resort to `ref` parameters:

```
public static void StrPassing(ref string someStr)
{
    string otherStr="Changed!";
    someStr=otherStr;
}
```

And call it like this:

```
string foo = "foo";
StrPassing(ref foo);
Console.WriteLine(foo); // should print "Changed!"
```

The `ref` keyword ensures that your method gets the actual reference to the string and can change it, instead of just a copy of the reference. So then you *can* replace the object by an entirely new one.

To come back to your array: You'd have a hard time too, to change the passed array to an entirely different array:

```
public static void NumPassing(int[] a)
{
    a = new int[15];
}
```

wouldn't work too because *then* you'd try exactly the same as changing a string to an entirely different string.

Comment: I don't think "by reference by value" is a particularly helpful term - separate what's being passed (a reference) from how it's being passed (by value). The leading "by" just adds to the confusion IMO.

Comment: You're right. I changed it to something more understandable (I hope). Resembles your words more now. Aaaand there goes my accepted answer. Drat.

Answer (score 1):

What you'd need to do is change the signature for `StrPassing` to look like this:

```
public static void StrPassing(ref string someStr)
```

Answer (score 0):

Strings are special in C#.  They are immutable reference types which makes they exhibit similar behavior as value types.

[Here's](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1658871/pretending-net-strings-are-value-type) a good discussion.

Comment: Being immutable doesn't make them *that* special - in particular, the compiler doesn't change how they're passed or anything like that.